# Twitter api using Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

im looking to make for a Twitter API that shows a certain term lets say "cheese" to appear on a html webpage showing a list of the latests tweets that mentioned cheese and is updated so any new tweets using cheese appear in the list. Can anyone help me on doing this. I know people will suggest PHP but i only want to use Javascript.

Comment: you mean nodeJS implementation of the hashtag search ?

Comment: exactly yes but showing on a webpage rather than a cmd prompt

Comment: do you know how Twitter REST API works?

Comment: https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=%cheese I am trying to use a track method like this

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use `node-twitter` npm package, which should significantly simplify the task. [Link here](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter)

You can use it as follows (`nodeJS` code follows):

```js
import Twitter from 'twitter';

var client = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: keys.consumer_key,
    consumer_secret: keys.consumer_secret,
    access_token_key: keys.access_token_key,
    access_token_secret: keys.access_token_secret
});


module.exports.getLatestTweetsByHashtag = function(hashtags, callback){
  //here hashtags is an array in the form: [#cheese, #bacon]
  var hashtagsToString = hashtags.join(" ");
  var encodedHashtags = encodeURIComponent(hashtags).replace(/%20/g, '+');
  client.get('search/tweets.json', {
    q: encodedHashtags,
    result_type: 'recent',
    include_entities: true
  }, function(error, tweets, response) {
    if (error) return callback(error);
    else return callback(undefined, tweets.statuses);
  });
}
```

The result can be retrieved from the method using callback (feel free to 'promisify` it if you wish)

Use as follows:

```js
require('./my-twitter-module').getLatestTweetsByHashtag(['#cheese'], function(err, tweets){
  //do error handling
  //pass it back to client side, tweets are already json object
  res.json(tweets);
});
```

**This will give you the list of most recents tweets containing all of the hashtags included in the array**

**EDIT**
In case if you are looking for streaming API implementation:

```js
client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: 'cheese'}, function(stream) {
  stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
    console.log(tweet.text);
  });

  stream.on('error', function(error) {
    throw error;
  });
});
```